# Always add trailing / to urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo

I now have :

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.co.uk$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk/$1/ [L,R=301]


    RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*)/([^/]+) fishery.php?url=$2&region=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*)/?$ region.php?region=$1 [L]      

    RewriteRule ^fishing?$ fishing.html [L]
```

I have added all the code to improve SEO. remove www. always add trailing / and so on. Problem is now when I do domain.co.uk/fishing/ it loads the region.php file instead of fishing.html

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for your new extended question, just move the

```
RewriteRule ^fishing?$ fishing.html [L]
```

above the previous two rules so it gets matched first.

And change it to

```
RewriteRule ^fishing/$ fishing.html [L]
```

Because you are forcing a trailing slash.

You can add something like this above the fishing.html one for css etc...

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: That loaded the correct page , but didnt load the css for the page? any reason for that ?

Comment: see my edits, I just noticed you are forcing a trailing slash in a previous rule...

Comment: Well your rules add trailing slashes and things like that

Comment: You'll need a rewritecond to stop rewriting css files, and probably javascript, images etc too

Comment: its stange because all the images, scripts still work.. just not the CSS.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="default" href="http://domain.co.uk/css/default.css/">

Comment: @andrewanderson: That's not a valid path. If you don't specify the `http://` at the front, it becomes a relative path. So it'll actually look for the file at `http://domain.co.uk/domain.co.uk/css/default.css/` - and get a 404.

Comment: @animuson sorry http:// is in the path it just made it a hyperlink when i pasted it in

Comment: @andrewanderson: Have you tried removing the `/` off the end of it?

Comment: @animuson yeah it didnt have the / i just added that in part way through this question. just tried it again now and it didnt make any difference

Comment: @appclay sorry i dont see any changes in your edit? might just be blind though.

Comment: the css/js/images thing I added at the bottom! :P

Comment: Well I made some assumptions about your directory structure... I'm surprised it didn't work for your css file though!

Comment: You can look at your apache error logs to check what file it actually looks for maybe...

Comment: ahh this is causing me major issues. Just noticed that fishery.php isnt displaying properlly either. Would it be easier for me to have a rule that removed a traling / ?

Comment: this is what that new rule I added was supposed to do, remove the trailing slash for anything under the css, js, or images folders.

Comment: i mean like remove instead of adding trailing slash to everything , remove it from everything instead. would that make it easier
?

Comment: I'd suggest checking your error logs first, it could give you some idea what's being served up when you try to get the default.css file.

Comment: my latest log file april week2 only goes to 2012-04-07 ??

Comment: That's a bit strange...  does your browser indicate that it's not receiving the css file?  What happens if you just browse to the css url?

Comment: @appclay to be honest with you i have just noticed i have been uploading the wrong version of the file which did not have absolute references. I have slapped myself in the face on your behalf. Sorry to have wasted so much of your time. If i can get the fishery.php page to work then ill be all sorted :D thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem, we all make mistakes like that sometimes! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is getting matched by something else before it gets to that spot. You need to re-order them. Less specific should be listed first, leading up to more specific.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^fishing/$ fishing.html [L]

RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*)/?$ region.php?region=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*)/([^/]+) fishery.php?url=$2&region=$1 [L]
```

Your path `fishing/` actually matches the rule `^fishing/([^/]*)/?$`. Being that it starts with `fishing/`, then there are 0 or more characters that aren't a `/` (there's 0, *match*), and there is 0 or 1 `/` at the end (there's 0, *match*), going to the end of the path.

---

Keep in mind that by forcing trailing slashes, that path becomes the **working directory**, so relative paths will start from that directory instead of the root. Make sure you are using **absolute paths** for things like CSS, JS, and images.

Comment: Thanks, yeah my problem is now with the css. although my path is and always has been an absolute and full path. not sure what else to do